# How to preserve-scroll with buttons using inertia js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

Working

```
<Link :href="route('products')" preserve-scroll>Products</Link>
```

Not Working

```
<form @submit.prevent="submit">
   ...
   <button type="submit" preserve-scroll>Submit</button>
</form>
```

package.json

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.10.1",
    "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.5.2",
    "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.6",
    "vue": "^3.2.20"
}
...
```

I haven't found a way in the inertia documentation to preserve scrolling when clicking on buttons, did someone face it yet?

Comment: it was not meant to work on anything except links. https://inertiajs.com/scroll-management

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell the request you're making at the `submit` method to `preserverScroll`. Something like this:

```js
submit () {
   this.$inertia.post(url, data, {
      preserveScroll: true
   })
}
```

And you can remove the `preserve-scroll` from the button. That is useless.