# How to enable preserve scroll on inertia?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a list with view records. When I update the `printflag`, the window scrolls on top, event the option `preserveScroll: true` is set.

Function in Vue:

```js
setPrintFlag(vinylRecord) {
  const self = this
  this.$inertia.put(route('vinylRecords.updatePrintFlag', vinylRecord.id),
    {
    print_flag: !vinylRecord.print_flag
  },
    {
      preserveState: true,
      preverseScroll: true
    }
  )
}
```

Function in backend (Laravel)

```php
public function updatePrintFlag(UpdatePrintFlagRequest $request, VinylRecord $vinylRecord)
{
  $data = $request->validated();

  $vinylRecord->update($data);

  return back();
}
```

When I read the doc, it looks all ok, but it doesn't work. Is there a missing param to enable the `preserveSroll`?

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69713963/8816585

Comment: Sorry for the question. It was only a typo....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a typo, OP initially wrote

```js
preverseScroll: true
```

while it's

```js
preserveScroll: true
```